# Will GIGABYTE motherboards BLACK EDITION be more wear out?

Tags: motherboard, computer-building, physical-wear

Will GIGABYTE motherboards BLACK EDITION be more wear out than its "ordinary version"?

For instances, [GA-Z97X-UD5H (rev. 1.1)](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5105) vs. [GA-Z97X-UD5H-BK (rev. 1.1) - BLACK EDITION](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5106).

As their specifications are almost the same, the different only lies into their **Extended server level 168 hour durability Test**.

If their components are identical, theoretically their lifespans should be the same. However the BLACK EDITION boards have been undergo 168 hours more of "extensive use" *before* purchase. So, will the BLACK EDITION counterparts are having 168 hours less lifespan?

Comment: 168 hours is one week.  For a component whose lifespan is measured in years, one week of use isn't really significant.

Comment: I understand this concern might be a bit picky. But that one week (168 hours) was used _continuously_ and _extensively_. For a non-server desktop used heavily, it might only run 8 hours a day, and not every second under high pressure. Testing is good. But if none or only very few of their boards died in the 168 hour test. I would rather prefer those without the pressure test.

Comment: Starting up and shutting down every day probably puts more stress on the board (due to thermal expansion) than running continuously; it's not like the wires get eroded by electrons going through.  I have a PC here with an Abit AB9 Pro motherboard that's been running continuously for about 8 years.  Don't worry about a week.

Answer (score 3):

I think the point of that test is to weed out boards of marginal quality that are likely to fail early in their lifetime.  Those that pass are likely to last much longer.  Read about the "[bathtub curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathtub_curve)" used in reliability engineering: defective units tend to fail quickly and non-defective units tend to last a long time.

If you think it's worth having confidence that your motherboard won't fail early, even if it means possibly failing a week sooner many years from now, buy the "black edition" board.  If you want to get that extra week of lifetime, but with an increased risk that the board might die a few days after you install it, buy the regular version.  Consider the price difference vs. the hassle of doing a warranty replacement.